# Programmatically reading the output of Hadoop Mapreduce Program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

This may be a basic question, but I could not find an answer for it on Google.
I have a map-reduce job that creates multiple output files in its output directory.
My Java application executes this job on a remote hadoop cluster and after the job is finished, it needs to read the output programatically using `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` API. Is it possible?
The application knows the output directory, but not the names of the output files generated by the map-reduce job. It seems there is no way to programatically list the contents of a directory in the hadoop file system API. How will the output files be read?

It seems such a commonplace scenario, that I am sure it has a solution. But I am missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The method you are looking for is called listStatus(Path).
It simply returns all files inside of a Path as a FileStatus array. Then you can simply loop over them create a path object and read it.

```
    FileStatus[] fss = fs.listStatus(new Path("/"));
    for (FileStatus status : fss) {
        Path path = status.getPath();
        SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, path, conf);
        IntWritable key = new IntWritable();
        IntWritable value = new IntWritable();
        while (reader.next(key, value)) {
            System.out.println(key.get() + " | " + value.get());
        }
        reader.close();
    }
```

For Hadoop 2.x you can setup the reader like this:

```
 SequenceFile.Reader reader = 
           new SequenceFile.Reader(conf, SequenceFile.Reader.file(path))
```

Comment: @Thomas,
listStatus also seems to return other files, e.g. _SUCCESS

Comment: Yes, but that is not my problem ;) You have to filter for yourself

Comment: can you please guide me how to filter _SUCCESS files?

Comment: @waqas use PathFilter (http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/PathFilter.html) and the FileSystem API above.

Comment: "new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, path, conf);" is deprecated in 2.0.0-cdh4.0.1

Comment: @xgMz yep it has been replaced by `Configuration`,`Reader.Option`. Works basically the same way. You just need to seed it with the `FileOption` that takes the path as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options: here are two that I sometimes use.

**Method #1:** Depending on your data size, is to make use of the following HDFS commands (found [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/05/10-mapreduce-tips), Item 6)

```
hadoop fs -getmerge hdfs-output-dir local-file
// example 
hadoop fs -getmerge /user/kenny/mrjob/ /tmp/mrjob_output
// another way
hadoop fs -cat /user/kenny/mrjob/part-r-* > /tmp/mrjob_output
```

"This concatenates the HDFS files hdfs-output-dir/part-* into a single local file."

Then you can just read in the one single file. (note that it is in local storage and not HDFS)

**Method #2**: Create a helper method: (I have a class called HDFS which contains the Configuration, FileSystem instances as well as other helper methods)

```
public List<Path> matchFiles(String path, final String filter) {
        List<Path> matches = new LinkedList<Path>();
        try {
            FileStatus[] statuses = fileSystem.listStatus(new Path(path), new PathFilter() {
                       public boolean accept(Path path) {
                          return path.toString().contains(filter);
                       }
                    });  
            for(FileStatus status : statuses) {
                matches.add(status.getPath());
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return matches;
    }
```

You can then call via a command like this: `hdfs.matchFiles("/user/kenny/mrjob/", "part-")`

Answer (score 0):

```
            FSDataInputStream inputStream = fs.open(path);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String record;
            while((record = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                int blankPos = record.indexOf(" ");
                System.out.println(record+"blankPos"+blankPos);
                String keyString = record.substring(0, blankPos);
                String valueString = record.substring(blankPos + 1);
                System.out.println(keyString + " | " + valueString);
            }
```