# Read from reducer output file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have some MapReduce job and I would like to use the output file of Reducer further in Java code. How can I read from such a file, since it's on distributed file system?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a file in Java hdfs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166123/reading-a-file-in-java-hdfs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically reading the output of Hadoop Mapreduce Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634137/programmatically-reading-the-output-of-hadoop-mapreduce-program)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use output file of Reducer further in a simple java code, for that you can use the following code:-

```
` try{
Path pt=new Path("hdfs://npvm11.np.wc1.yellowpages.com:9000/user/john/abc.txt");
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
    String line;
    line=br.readLine();
    while (line != null){
    System.out.println(line);
    line=br.readLine();
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
                }`
```

Replace the address with the address of file which you want to use in java code.