# Process large data from external drive using Hadoop without moving it to HDFS

Tags: hadoop

I'm beginner to Hadoop, and I have singe node hadoop running in 250 GB linux.

And I have an external hard drive which has more that 1 TB of data.

My question is how to make this data visible to Hadoop without copying them into HDFS.

I tried to put the mounted hard drive to datanode.dir, but I could not see the files.

Comment: Are you just trying to learn Hadoop or are you actually trying to solve a problem.  If the latter, I wouldn't even bother using Hadoop with only a single node.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data using the [LocalFileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) if you have a Hadoop client on the same machine as the one connected to the external HD.

For example, you can run:

```
hadoop fs -ls file://path/to/external/dir
```

The command above should list the contents to the local absolute path specified.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given above will show the content which is already there in HDFS.

`"hadoop fs -ls"` command is used to see the content present in HDFS.

As HDFS is a different file system from  the file system of your personal machine so you can not see the data of present on you local machine using
`"hadoop fs -ls file://path/to/external/directory"`.

But you can access data of your external hard drive in hadoop programs  a simple code snippet for accessing data from local machine in a mapreduce job can be found in the following question:- [Reading data from local machine directly in map reduce jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617971/read-from-reducer-output-file/27644962#27644962)

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not possible. Hadoop emphasize "Data Localization" which is one of a key  design factor that makes  Hadoop different from classy grid computing. This also a reason why both HDFS and MapReduce  deployed  together in nodes.

Data Localization improves computing speed in many ways. It is not possible boz of other few more design and performance reasons. I would suggest you to look into HDFS concepts..

Hope this is helpful!